# Middleware de laravel funciona mal en GAE (Google App Engine)

Tags: mysql, eloquent, google-app-engine

Estoy teniendo un problema con un middleware cuando corro mi app en GAE. Este se encarga de realizar una validación básica en consultas a mi api. Lo que hace básicamente es tomar un "api_token" que se envia el header de cada consulta y verifica si le corresponde a algún usuario. En caso de **NO** ser valido, retorna un código 401 con un texto "No autorizado". Lo raro es, que en local funciona correctamente pero en el servidor siempre retorna 401. Analizando un poco el comportamiento aparentemente la consulta del token a la db no retorna ningún usuario. Mas abajo dejo algunas pruebas que hice, por las cuales demuestro que el usuario existe, el token se está enviando en el header y se corresponde con el mismo almacenado en la db.

**Middleware:**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $user = User::where('api_token', $request->header('api_token'))->first();

        if ($user === null) {
            return response()->json ('No autorizado', 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

*Aparentemente **$user** siempre es null.*

**Captura de request desde el navegador:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Captura de request y response desde Postman:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Captura de usuario con su correspondiente api_token en la DB:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Importante: NO** hay problema de conexión con la DB, si des-habilito el middleware para la rutas las consultas funcionan perfectamente. Muchas gracias desde ya, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre solucionarlo… con mucha paciencia y después de varias pruebas logre detectar el error.

Primero modifique mi middleware incorporando `dd($request->header('api_token'));` e hice un nuevo deploy. Con esto logre visualizar que este código por algún motivo no estaba funcionando en GAE y siempre retornaba Null aunque enviase el header “api_token”. Pensé que el método header() podía ser el responsable así que modifique nuevamente mi middleware reemplazando lo anterior por `dd($request->headers);` e hice un nuevo deploy. En este punto, logre determinar que por más que estuviese enviando mi header tanto desde Postman como del browser, no estaba llegando a mi servidor, algo en el camino lo estaba eliminando o bloqueando! 
Despues de esto, en un momento de iluminación, me percaté de que todos los headers personalizados de Laravel son emitidos con ciertas convenciones. Las palabras separadas por “-“ y no por “_” como hice yo, por otro lado eran enviados en mayúsculas. Así que hice una prueba, reemplace “**api_token**” por “**API-TOKEN**” en mi consulta con Postman y Voilá! Ahora mi servidor recibía dicho header. Entonces hice los ajustes pertinentes en el middleware también y problema resuelto!

Espero ahorrarle el dolor de cabeza a alguno. Saludos!